# Azure AD Application Role Authorization: Tenant Admin Delegation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to delegate role assignment to an admin of a tenant, so he can add and remove members, but only from his domain/org?

Comment: Please explain more about your requirement . Do you want to delegate admin role to your application  ,so in application can manager the users in the tenant ?

Comment: Application admins can add users and groups to roles of an application.  In a multi-tenant scenario, multiple tenants will access this application.  Each tenant will have users and groups that will want to be added to roles in the app.  Is it possible to have the admins of each tenant to add his own users and groups to the roles of this app?  I don't see any other way of explaining this... @NanYu

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-tenant scenario, when a user from a different tenant signs in to the application for the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions requested by the application. If they consent, then a representation of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s tenant .

The `Enterprise Applications` blade represents service principals in your AAD . Then you could assign a user or a group to a role of your enterprise application.Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal) for how to achieve that .